# Initiate sleep power state on PC from USB

Tags: usb, sleep, power, power-management

I have been looking at designing an external pcb to turn on and off the PC, and lately I have been thinking of ways to improve this construction.
After a few quick googles searches I found you could use the power button to instead put the PC to sleep, but this is not what I'm looking for, instead I was wondering if it would be possible to initiate sleep on Windows or Linux from a USB port, if there is some commonly used signal or packet etc.?

Comment: USB HID power buttons: [there's plenty of novelty buttons](https://www.theregister.com/2006/07/18/usb_nuclear_war_button_box/) on Amazon:

Comment: But that is not an amazon link?